# Firebase duplicates a node instead of deleteing it when removeValue is called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase database tree like this:

[image]

I am trying to delete the entire node `-Ka4ytRxQIrzXRR7eSti` from iOS app and here is what I do in code:

```
private let usersDatabase = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

func deleteNode() {
    guard let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        assertionFailure("No user logged in when deleting a node")
        return 
    }
    usersDatabase.child(userID).child("-Ka4ytRxQIrzXRR7eSti").removeValue()
}
```

Instead of deleting the node this duplicates it! The new auto id is generated for the duplicated node and all the data from the original node `-Ka4ytRxQIrzXRR7eSti` are copied (keys and values) to the duplicated node. Where is the catch?

Comment: What happens if you try `.setValue(nil)` at that child reference?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Exactly the same thing: The node gets duplicated. At least that part of documentation where they say *`removeValue` is  equivalent to calling `setValue:nil`* is correct :(

Comment: Dang. Could you try calling the `removeValue` method that has a completion block, and see if any error is returned? `func removeValue(completionBlock block: @escaping (Error?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)`

Comment: Seems to me like the error's probably elsewhere: a listener being fired when you make that change?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary I also thought that is more likely but after verifying everything 10 times over I have to admit a posibility of FB or FBSDK issue...  Yes, listener fires for addition of the new node. Firebase console shows deletion of a node for split of a second but then the node is retained and a copy is added... Really strange.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Will try and let you know.

Comment: While it is definitely possible that a Firebase SDK has a bug, it seems unlikely that the simple snippet you shared wouldn't have been discovered before. The last time a developer reported a rogue append-upon-delete, it turned out they had an unexpected listener left behind that re-added the node. The time before that, it was a server-side process they forgot to stop.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to reproduce this on a different node or even new database. Also: enable debug logging and check what it sends/receives: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the tips. I understand how unlikely such a bug is given the number of FB users. I am trying to make sure that it's not something like that for last couple of hours. The problem is that I have single data listener and the code triggered by it does not write anything to FB nor do I have any servers connected. I will update you soon.